# How to make contentScript run before contentScriptFile?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a FF addon recently. My addon will download some configuration files before the contentScriptFile been evaluated. My code is like this:

```
panel.on("show", function() {
var url = "http://domain/config.js";
request({
    url:url,
    onComplete: function(response) {
        worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
           contentScript:response.text,
           contentScriptFile: [data.url("js/do1.js"), data.url("js/do2.js")]
         });
        ...
    }
  })
}
```

But as your document has said that contentScriptFile will be run before contentScript, so if I do want to run contentScript first, how should I do?
I have tried to attach twice, first attach contentScript only, then attach contentScriptFile, but not success.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You must not execute remote scripts in a privileged context, or execute insecure remote scripts in a potentially secure context. What you're asking fails both:

1. Executing remote scripts in a somewhat privileged context, namely a content script, which has some privileged capabilities regular web site scripts have not.
2. Execute an insecure `http://` script (you gave that in the example), in the current tab, which might be `https://`. This would allow Man-in-the-Middle attacks. (Even if you served your "config" from `https`, the add-on site would still reject your submission, BTW, because it cannot be reviewed as the active content is not complete).

So, effectively, you got two security vulnerabilities, both of which can and should [make your add-on end up on the blocklist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_guidelines#Be_Safe).

However, you can retrieve your configuration using a *non-active/non-executable format*, such as **JSON** or **XML** (or plain text, if you like).

Passing these configuration values can be achieved by

- using either `contentScriptOptions` (which is not documented in `tabs` nor `worker`, but in [`page-mod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29) but should work for all, as a cursory test shows). Full example:

  ```
  var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

  tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
    tab.attach({
      contentScript: 'console.log(self.options);',
      contentScriptOptions: {"abc": 123}
    });
  });
  ```
- Or [regular messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on).

Comment: Thank you for you detailed guide. I know how to deal with it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`data.load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data.load(name)) from the `self` SDK module to load the content script in a string and append the values to the `contentScript` array:

```js
worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScript: [
        response.text,
        data.load("js/do1.js"),
        data.load("js/do2.js")
    ]
});
```

Comment: You could, but you really shouldn't. This will most certainly get you on the blocklist once discovered for executing remote scripts in a (somewhat) privileged context, which is a security vulnerability.

Comment: @nmaier `data.load` with a relative path returns the contents of a file that is bundled with a SDK addon.

Comment: Yeah, but `response.text` most certainly does not ;) I should have been more clear in my comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Regardless of safety concern, your method is really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @user2552042 While it works at the moment, I strongly suggest to take a serious look at @nmaler's suggestion. For configuration, `contentScriptOptions` is the way to go. Only use the method in my answer for static content scripts that are bundled with your extension.